# Scroll page for everyone who is on that page, on your scroll

Tags: javascript, web, websocket

Is it possible to use make the following functionality with JavaScript:

Let's say we have 3 different people on 3 different devices on example.com

Can we mimic the scroll on everyone's device once  someone scrolls the page?

Do you think web sockets can help here?

Bonus functionality: also mimic the clicks and redirects to oder pages

TLDR: Replicate BrowserSync but without NodeJS, online, on public domain and for everyone present.

Comment: Answer: yes. you can use event handlers to trigger sending data through the socket. I am uncertain as to if web sockets is the only way of doing so, but it'd be the only way I'd know of. Worth mentioning: you shouldn't be able to be able to access anything outside of the website your on, so if you are trying to create like an RDP using nodejs and websockets, it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @Shmack Thanks for your reply! Forgot to mention, it would be PHP/WordPress stack. Seems possible?

Comment: You need websockets and PHP/WP makes this even harder, last I checked websocket support is shaky at best in PHP

Comment: Oh, I misread - I saw with node. I have little experience with both WP and PHP (mainly because my boss had a WP website and it forced me to use PHP). Barely enough to maybe be dangerous. I highly doubt that there are plugins available for WP that do websockets. There would be some custom code involved. I don't think the fact that it is WP based matters, ultimately, but maybe I'm wrong. You would have to write a custom plugin or theme to handle the websockets' backend and the javascript logic to communicate through the websocket, etc.

Comment: @shmack Thanks for the commend! I made this whole thing today and it works perfectly. WP Plugin just inserts JS code into the frontend which communicates with my nodejs socket.io server hosted on Heroku. I also added socket rooms so every website has his own room.
To enable plugin just add "?sync" at the end of url and write that URL on any device you want to include. Also added page redirection on all devices once you change page on main device. Used some WP filters to keep "?sync" GET param on all pages
DEMO https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OKuhI8NxFXfrm1noZEhx0BqQK6eBKFK3/view?usp=sharing